# IS media-query will work in I

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

IS media-query will work in IE8 Iframe?

I want to load responsive website in iframe (width:600).media-query is taking all browsers but in IE its not taking. how to fix it?

Is there any solution apart form media-query

i've tried "css3-mediaqueries-js"

Thanks
Shanid kv

Answer (score 0):

No, mediaqueries don't work in IE8 : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Rather than trying to find a workaround for this old browser, I would suggest to find a gracefull fallback, or better, not support it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another polyfill for mediaqueries - https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 480px){
    ...styles for 480px and up go here
}
```

and reference the js file in the link on your page

Answer (score 0):

@all,

I got the solution instead of writing media query we can do with "max-width" and "percentage width". in this case it will work in IE8 also.

here is the example

http://scottjehl.github.io/Respond/test/test.html

Thanks 
shanid kv